# How to pass data between different c# and javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have an ascx page with a div, when the div is clicked it calls a JS function and send an int

//HTML

```
<div style="float: right; margin-right: 150px;" class="innerDivStyle"
onclick="userStartExtend(2)">        
        <h1 style="margin-top: 50px">Product</h1>
    </div>
```

//JavaScript function

```
 function userStartExtend(num) {}
```

I need to use the num from userStartExtend function in a c# (file/page/code). I thought about querystring - set in javascript code and get in c# (possible?). Any other ideas ??
To make things clear : the c# code and javascript code dont share the same page.

Comment: The details are little vague. When the page is rendered to the browser, is the js code and that div rendered in the same html document ?

Comment: It's *really* unclear what you're trying to accomplish.  So... a numeric value is calculated in `userStartExtend()`.  Where is the server-side code going to need this value?  Does the value need to be calculated client-side?  If the server-side code needs it on a later page, can you put it in the query string for a link to that page?  If it needs it on the current page, can you send the value to the server in an AJAX call?

Comment: yes the div and js code are in the same document, only the c# is in a different page

Comment: you can run an ajax webmethod inside your javascript http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

Comment: I will try to clear it.. user need to choose an option he click on the div after he clicked the div he(user) will get a certain info. For example he clicked on the div above and the number 2 is passed to userStartExtend function. in another ascx I need to show data according to the user choise, in this case i need the number two to know what the user choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What one normally does in a case where he wants to pass something from Javascript to .NET he uses eventHandlers, just don't forget to add attributes [**`runat="server" id="DivId"`** and event handler **`OnServerClick="DivHandler"`**.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7512d0d0(v=vs.100).aspx)

Example:

```
<div runat="server" id="DivId" OnServerClick="DivHandler" style="float: right; margin-right: 150px;" class="innerDivStyle" onclick="userStartExtend(2)"  >        
    <h1 style="margin-top: 50px">Product</h1>
</div>
```

then on C# side

```
public void DivHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //here sender is your <div> and e is data about 'click' event.
}
```

**UPDATE:** It appears that `OnServerClick` does not work properly ether. Here is workaround

HTML:

```
<div runat="server" id="DivId" OnServerClick="testMe('param1')" style="float: right; margin-right: 150px;" class="innerDivStyle" onclick="userStartExtend(2)"  >        
    <h1 style="margin-top: 50px">Product</h1>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function testMe(params) {
    var btnID= '<%=MyButton.ClientID %>';          
    __doPostBack(btnID, params);
}
```

Server-side Page_Load:

```
 string parameter = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
 if (parameter == "param1")
     MyButton_Click(sender, e);
```

Comment: Tried this,the function was not fired. the function was undefined

Comment: @Damkulul my bad attribute name is `OnServerClick` here's an article on how to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7512d0d0(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Make your `div` server side

```
<div id="serverSideId" runat="server" />
```

In your C# code, Page_PreRender should have this

```
int myValue = 2;
serverSideId.OnClientClick = "userStartExtend(" + myValue.ToString() + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden Field control in your use control

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnval" runat="server" Value="" Visible="false">
```

update your javascript function as this

```
function userStartExtend(num) {
var myHidden=  document.getElementById('<%= hdnval.ClientID %>');

 if(myHidden)
 {
 myHidden.value=num;
 }

}
```

Now use can access this server control at  code behind